# css link button selected color

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, selected

PHP LINK :

```
 $getOID=$_GET["id"];
    for($i=$getOID-($getOID-1); $i<=5;$i++){
    echo '<a class="current" href="postlogin.php?id='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
     }
```

CSS BUTTON :

```
.pagging { height:20px; padding:8px 10px; line-height:19px; color:#949494; }
.pagging a{ background:url(images/pagging.gif) repeat-x 0 0; height:20px; float:left; padding:0 8px; border:solid 1px #d5d5d5; text-decoration: none; color:#949494; margin-left:5px;  }
.pagging a:hover { border-color:#8c3521; background:#ba4c32; color:#fff; }
.pagging a.current { background:#ba4c32; color:#fff; }
.pagging span{ float:left; margin-left:5px; padding-top:2px; }
```

My all buttons look like selected. How can i fix this code i want to see only selected button different color.

Comment: *"When i came button i can change color with hover. How can i add select css selected button will be colorful so i would see which button selected."* - could you please rewrite this to be understandable.

Comment: `.pagging a:visited { color: red; }` ?

Comment: *"All my buttons look like selected."* - what do your selected buttons look like? You haven't defined a unique style for selected buttons, or at least explained how that style should be different.

Comment: My buttons appear with for loop how can i select unique style ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first to prevent a php notice and also for your security reason:

```
$getOID = (isset($_GET["id"])) ? (int)$_GET["id"] : 0;
```

For your css try:

`.pagging .current a { background:red; color:#fff; }`

`.pagging .current a:hover { border-color:#000; background:darkred; color:#fff; }`